# Fixing the Sampling Rate of ADC in ESP8266 Wi-Fi Module

Tags: esp8266

What is the sampling rate of the internal ADC of ESP8266 Wi-Fi module and how can I fix it to some other value by programming it in Arduino IDE? Please help.

Comment: Sorry, not in scope here, please ask on Arduino Stack Exchange.

Comment: a simple google search suggests that the **maximum** sampling rate is 2.5kHz